# How to separate date and time from an imported excel file? (Laravel)

Tags: excel, laravel

I am working with Laravel and I need to import an excel file that contains employees' attendance records. The file contains the Date/Time column. I want to separate the date and time from that column and store them in separate columns in the database table. Also, is there any way to change the format of date in accordance with the Mysql database format i.e from the format in the sheet to yyyy-mm-dd?

[Attendance sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFXVc.png)

Comment: Use Carbon Library in laravel to manipulate datetime https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function to extract date and time as below.

```
$dateTime = explode(" ", $row[3]);
Or
$dateTime = explode(" ", trim($row[3])); // if there may be spaces in the beginning or end

// $dateTime[0] is your date
// $dateTime[1] is your time
```

if you are still confused you can look at a simple php script below

```
<?php
    $refDate = '1/12/2021 14:44';

    $dateTime = explode(" ", $refDate);

    var_dump($dateTime);

?>

// OUTPUT
array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "1/12/2021" [1]=> string(5) "14:44" }
```

And as mentioned above you can use Carbon Library to manipulate date time.